# Apply outer border for the highchart area chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am implementing the area chart as shown in the mock up, but have strict at some portion and not able to get option s that are available in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts for configuring the chart to look as is.

Here is the mock up look.

[image]

What I have achieved so far is :

> [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpvph/3/)

So I could not able to achieve the

1.background color

```
backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: false,
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
                ]
            },
```

2 . Only outer border line. (As shown in the mock up)
[image]

3 . On Hover Show All 3 labels. (As shown in the mock up)

4 . Legend like "CPM IMPS SPEND BY TIME" with colors I mean I want to acheive same as in mock up.

[image]

**Last Point to implement :**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..

1.background color:

```
chart: {
   backgroundColor: 'black', //for whole plot


name: 'IMPS',
data: [
...
], color: 'rgb(213, 156, 72)' //for one area
```

2 . Only outer border line. (As shown in the mock up)

```
   yAxis: [{

        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0
    }, {

        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true
    }],
```

3 . On Hover Show All 3 labels. (As shown in the mock up)

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b> <br/>', //like in mock up
  shared: true, //all series
  crosshairs: true //vertical line
},
```

4 . Legend like "CPM IMPS SPEND BY TIME" with colors I mean I want to acheive same as in mock up.

so I already answered how do it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278211/need-to-apply-background-color-to-each-legend-text-highchart/24279648#24279648)

Last Point to implement :

js:

```
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            padding: 0
        },
```

and now you can customize your tooltip like you want:

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span p {
    margin: 0;
}
.highcharts-tooltip>span span{
    display: none;
}
#pCPM{background: rgb(87, 188, 0);}
#pIMPS{background: rgb(213, 156, 72);}
#pSPEND{background: rgb(12, 170, 226);}
```

Highchart's API don't allows you to set current values on axis, but you can disable default labels and put handmade labels with position absolute like I already doing with legend.

Summary [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/rwQDJ/)

Comment: "2 . Only outer border line. (As shown in the mock up)" As you can see in the mockup only one horizontal line along x-axis having values like week1, week2... And 2 border lines along the y-axis at both ends.

Comment: Just have a look at the question again, have attached a new image having arrows to it.

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks a lot for the help so far, but I think, you have missed one point, So I have updated a last point like: "Last Point to implement :" please see the image shown, and help me out, if you can achieve this. :)

Comment: man you are g for genius, Thanks for the help so far, you desire for (tick).

Comment: Hey dude, I have some issue related to the OOP kind of highchart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426303/implemention-highcharts-in-oop-javascript , Can you help me in this.

Comment: hey dude, hope you will help me in this small issues, please have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587040/highcharts-sticky-labels-for-big-values-goes-out-of-chart