# Need to apply background color to each legend text highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

As I stated in my question, I am looking to change my legend some like :

FROM:

[image]

TO

[image]

I have tried this for background color:

```
legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#CCC',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 60,
            y: 1,
            shadow: false, 
            border: 0, 
            borderRadius: 0, 
            borderWidth: 0
        },
```

But No luck
As you can see I have to achieve 
1. background colors to be applied to text .
2. And the text should be appended with 'BY TIME'.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpvph/6/)

Hope you guys help me, please ask if in need to more information.

Comment: I've checked  the documentation of Highcharts and it seems they don't have anything to do something like this. If I were you, I would try to add some Javascript/JQuery code to get the legend part using class `.highcharts-legend-item`, get the name and the color, and replace the html code with a simple html code that fits your purposes, like a div with 3 spans, each span with the background color you got from the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Liarez says, you can't do what you want from highcharts API.

But you can use jquery to do exactly what you want:

add new buttons:

```
<div id="legend">
<a href="#" id="a1">CPM</a>

<a href="#" id="a2">IPMS</a>

<a href="#" id="a3">SPEND</a>

</div>
```

add style to customize them:

```
#legend {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: black;
}
#legend a {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.leg-clicked {
    color: #CCC !important;
}
#a1 {
    background: rgb(87, 188, 0);
}
#a2 {
    background: rgb(213, 156, 72);
}
#a3 {
    background: rgb(12, 170, 226);
}
```

and the trick here:

css:

```
.highcharts-legend{display: none;}
```

js:

```
$("#a1").click(function () {
    $('.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(1)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass("leg-clicked");
});
$("#a2").click(function () {
    $('.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(2)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass("leg-clicked");
});
$("#a3").click(function () {
    $('.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(3)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass("leg-clicked");
});
```

so highchart's legend is invisible and our custom buttons are sending clicks to legend. It is trick of course, but all works.

Also you can add any css you want, images, another jquery effects to this buttons.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/49pre/)

Comment: thanks, may I request you for one more help?, just go here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265785/apply-outer-border-for-the-highchart-area-chart  and have a look at the question. have to achieve like the given mockup. And for this answer, you won :)