# Implementing highcharts in OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, highcharts

I want to implement highcharts in full object oriented way and fully configurable. So that I can just  call the object and pass in the values for the options the chart should display.

So I started with creating a function like: `highchartclass` , please look at the code below:

```
$(function () {
    var highchartclass = {
        create: function (toId, type) {
            return new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: toId,
                    type: type,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                },
                legend: {},
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {},
                yAxis: [],
                tooltip: {},
                plotOptions: {},
                series: []
            });
        }
    };
    var chartObj = highchartclass.create('container', 'area');
    chartObj.setTitle({
        text: 'CPM IMPS SPEND BY TIME'
    });

    var chartOptions = Highcharts.getOptions();
    console.log("======Present chartOptions==========");
    console.log(chartObj.options);

    chartObj.options.plotOptions['area'] = {
        pointStart: 1,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            symbol: 'circle',
            radius: 1,

            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
    chartObj.options['xAxis'] = {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return 'Week ' + this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    };

    chartObj.options['yAxis'] = [{

        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {

            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0
    }, {

        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {

            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true
    }];
    chartObj.options.tooltip = {
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            padding: 0
        },
        pointFormat: '<p id="p{series.name}"><b>${point.y:,.0f}</b></p>',
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    };
    chartObj.options.series = [{
        name: 'CPM',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640],
        color: 'rgb(87, 188, 0)'
    }, {
        name: 'IMPS',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 100, 126, 160, 269, 60, 165, 471, 322
        ],
        color: 'rgb(213, 156, 72)'
    }, {
        name: 'SPEND',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            50, 215, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 150, 160, 165, 171, 50
        ],
        color: 'rgb(12, 170, 226)'


    }];


    // Highcharts.setOptions(chartObj);
    console.log("======After chartOptions==========");
    console.log(chartOptions);
    console.log("======Chart Object==========");
    console.log(chartObj);

});
```

> [Fiddle Demo OOP](http://jsfiddle.net/GEBjE/159/)

I need to create a OOP kind of highchart, so by calling the getter or setter methods, the chart should be drawn,

Need to know, why the OOP kind of chart is not drawn, and also need to improvement on that.

The Normal way of the same chart looks like:

> [Actual chart without OOP](http://jsfiddle.net/GaHmU/2/)

Comment: Generally, you should initialsize your chart after setting options, not try to overwrite it as you have. In other words, set all options which you need and then call create with these pareamters.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, dear friend, Thanks for the info, but can you please give with some more explanation and a small demo atleast, hope you understand

Comment: There is not `watch` or anything similar on properties, so setting like `chartObj.options.series` does nothing. If you want to set anything, use API: [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart). Just like you did for a title, using `setTitle()`. When you want to add series, then use `addSeries()` etc. And example of Sebastians' idea: http://jsfiddle.net/GEBjE/160/