# Highcharts sticky labels for big values goes out of chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have two issue to request for help,

1. Have an issue with the highcharts, it looks like some calculation needs to be done for the chart, but could not ale to figure out the actual thing.

please look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/3/)  , In this the label at the right hand side `$500` is at the correct position that is ok, but when the value is big/large, lets say `$555555555555`, then the 
chart label goes out of chart.  Have a look at this fiddle now

[Fiddle having Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/6/)

Error:

[image]

what should happen is that the `$555555555555` should be inside the chart only, having the same position as show in the first fiddle.

What I tried.

Adding/subtracting the length of the string (`point.y`)  with + 30

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
    ....
    /*********RIGHT SIDE CPM*******************/     
    var point = chart.series[0].data[7];
    var text = chart.renderer.text(
        '$'+point.y, 
        point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 30, 
    //  point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - ( ((point.y).toString().length) + 30 ), //My change 
    ...
});
```

But this `point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - ( ((point.y).toString().length) + 30 ),` did not support when the value again changes from `$555555555555` to `$5`

so Basically the position should not vary when the length of the label is big/small.

My next question, The chart is starting with a small displacement at both sides.
have a look at the image below

[image]

As you can see the gap between the two red lines, at both the corners in the image, I need to remove that, It may be a padding issue, but I could not able to figure it out.

Please help me in this two issues.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue: Aligning rendered text**

So from reading your code I think you are trying to adjust the position of the text and box from the length of the content. Problem here is you have a font that has variable width characters while subtracting a constant value per character. Also, the `renderer.text` method always anchors in the bottom left, which isn't in your favor.

What I would do here is leverage that the `text.getBBox` knows the exact bounding box of the text `Element`. You might be able to get this to look a bit better, but here's a crude example:

```
/*********RIGHT SIDE CPM*******************/

var point = chart.series[0].data[7];
// Draw dummy text, just to get bounding box
var text = chart.renderer.text('$'+point.y, 0, 0)
    .attr({
        zIndex: 5
    }).add();
// Get bounding box
var box = text.getBBox();
// Destroy dummy text
text.destroy();

// Draw actual text based on bounding box
text = chart.renderer.text(
        '$'+point.y, 
        point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - box.width + 2 ,
        point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    ).attr({
        zIndex: 5
    }).add();

// Get actual box
box = text.getBBox();
// Draw actual box
chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
    .attr({
        fill: '#FFFFEF',
        stroke: 'gray',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        zIndex: 4
    })
    .add();
```

And [a JFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/8/) (I only bothered to fix your right side CPM, but you get the point).

**Issue: Spacing on sides of graph**

Set the `min` and `max` of your x-axis to specific values, as shown in [the JFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/8/), with the code:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    min: 1,
    max: 8
}
```

Comment: hey dude, thank you very much, you earned it, Can I ask you for one more suggestion or help, I changed your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/9/ , so what if all the last values become '5555555' , then it is overlapping on one another, Please suggest me any idea if you have, or with a modified code would be great. Thanks once again Sir.

Comment: I'm not sure. If you start moving them it might give the wrong impression of the y-axis. To avoid the text overlapping I would just give each text+box a separate zIndex. Perhaps you can find out which one has the highest value and then give it a significantly bigger zIndex, to go on top.

Comment: sir can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658332/highcharts-custom-display-of-tooltips-based-on-data-series-values . And please help me in which ever point you can